# Not able to close drawer

Tags: android

I have this code during pressing of back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isShown()) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    } else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

If the drawer is open, then presing the back button the drawer closes, but again pressing the back button app is not closing. I want when the drawer is not open then app will close upon pressing of back button. What to do ?

Comment: @  Mithun then what is use of if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen()`, not `isShown()`, which will always return true in this case. That will cause the `else` part of the `if` statement never to be executed.

Comment: with isDrawerOpen() u opened my eye also ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `isShown()` method is a member of the `View` class, and concerns visibility. You probably want one of the `DrawerLayout#isDrawerOpen()` methods instead.

Comment: with isDrawerOpen() u opened my eye also ;)

Answer (score 0):

isShown() always return true.
Use following fields as well.

```
mDrawerLayout.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```